# How to evaluate mathematics in Ubuntu console?

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu, math, console

When I try to calculate a maths problem such as 1 + 1 using the Ubuntu console like this:

```
user@servername:~$ 1 + 1
```

Ubuntu thinks the first `1` is a command and I get this error:

```
1: command not found
```

I then tried to use echo to evaluate the string (with and without quotes) like this:

```
user@servername:~$ echo 1 + 1
user@servername:~$ echo "1 + 1"
```

Unfortunatly both output `1 + 1` and not `2`.

It would also be greatly appreciated to include a explanation as to why `echo` does not evaluate the specified string before outputting it?

Also is there is a built-in command that evaluates a string before outputting it (maybe something that behaves like eval in Python)?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Enter `python` then you can do `1+1`.

Comment: @Cyrus I used to use that but I no longer want to be use Python for such a simple task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one I usually use is

```
bc<<<2+2
```

You can make that easier to type with an alias:

```
$ alias x='bc<<<'
$ x 53*(27-23)
212
```

If you put whitespace in the expression you'll need to quote it. Also if the expression starts with an open parenthesis (as opposed to having one in the middle).

Comment: Whoah!  +1 for introducing me to bash <<< magic!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo $((1+1))
2

$ echo "1+1" | bc
2

$ awk 'BEGIN{print 1+1}'  
2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I appreciate it, but I don't understand the difference between each method, could you please explain it?

Comment: first one shell does the computation, second is the `bc` calculator, third one is the `awk` script.  For simple integer arithmetic first one is fine and third one is the most flexible if you need formatting, if-then-else logic etc. `bc` is the most common one, for floating point you need to use the `-l` option, otherwise answers will be truncated to int.